# КулинАрия или кулинарИя?

Tags: ударение

КулинАрия или кулинарИя? Ведь подобные слова - ветеринАрия, филантрОпия, инженЕрия и т.д. - значит, и кулинАрия?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для современного русского языка совсем недавно равноправны были оба варианта: и кулинАрия и кулинарИя. Раньше допускалось  только кулинАрия, так же как слово "семинАрия". Но в связи с последней реформой кулинАрия считается устаревшим, а нормой - кулинарИя.

Comment: А когда была эта последняя реформа?

И спасибо за ответ, это интересно. Я **знаю** из словарей (Ожегова, например), что надо говорить "кулинАрия". Но в живой **разговорной** речи лично мне такого практически не приходится встречать. По ТВ -- да, слышу. Значит, произношение **"кулинарИя"** признали нормой?

Comment: Это я утрированно назвала реформой Приказ Минобрнауки России об утверждении списка грамматик, словарей и справочников от 06 августа  2009 :1. Орфографический словарь русского языка. Букчина Б.З., Сазонова И.К., Чельцова Л.К. 
     2. Грамматический словарь русского языка: Словоизменение. Зализняк А.А. 
     3. Словарь ударений русского языка. Резниченко И. Л. - М.: 
     4. Большой фразеологический словарь русского языка. Значение. Употребление. Культурологический комментарий. Телия В.Н. 
О реформе:http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-22204.html?page=8

Comment: См.: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/4398/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Согласно Орфоэпическому словарю Т.Ивановой (2006 год):

КулинАрия, КулинАрии, о кулинАрии...

Допускается КулинарИя, кулинарИи, о кулинарИи

Лично меня вариант "Допускается" никогда не интересовал.  Сейчас и кофе допускается называть ОНО...  Как говорила бабуля моего друга: Куда мы "котимся?" :)